# If $|z|<1$ then $|z+3-4i|<6$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

> Show that if $|z|<1$ then $|z+3-4i|<6$.

I tried using the triangle inequality but it seemed to not work at first. Is this correct? $$|z+3-4i| \leq |z| + |3-4i| = |z| + 5 < 1 + 5 = 6$$

Am I even supposed to use the triangle inequality here?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Only replace the last inequality sign by the "=" sign.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Thank you.

Comment: @user376984 It's true. Draw it in the Gauss plane.